# How to push existing docker image to google app-engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am currently using the app engine maven plugin, which seems to trigger a Google cloud build to build a docker image and then push to app engine.

Is it possible for me to just push an exiting docker image from docker hub or google container registry?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can deploy to App Engine using a specific Docker image hosted on Google Container Registry by using the `--image-url` flag like this:

```
gcloud app deploy --image-url=[HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]
```

See doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling#pushing_an_image_to_a_registry) for more info on the hostname options.

Comment: Check also [this link](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/using-with-google-cloud-platform#deploying_to) for the command explanation.

Comment: @LundinCast I am following same but ERROR - (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Deployment cannot use a pre-built image. Pre-built images are only allowed in the App Engine Flexible Environment, How do I specify environment in app engine

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to do this through the `Dockerfile` in your app directory.

I noticed this while searching for ways to [customize Google's own NGINX](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart) container in the App Engine instance (this is what is used to serve your app).

The first line of the Nginx Dockerfile is `FROM nginx`. This is referencing the 'nginx' image in the default image repository. As such this could be any image in the default registry as referenced by name. The default registry seems to be the Docker-hub registry (did not investigate if Google is mirroring or similar).

In this way, your app directory only need contain 2 files: `app.yaml` and `Dockerfile`.